# How to create login form in asp.net using a stored procedure?

Tags: asp.net, sql-server-2008

I am new to coding and asp.net can any one help me I am trying to create user login using a stored procedure but I'm getting an error.

I am posting my code with error please check and help me. Thanks

Code for data access :

```
public class DataAcc
{
    SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["cn"].ConnectionString);

    public DataSet DA_Bind()
    {
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("Sp_select", con);

        SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
        DataSet ds = new DataSet();
        da.Fill(ds);
        return ds;
    }
}
```

Business logic code:

```
public class business
{
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
    DataAcc sda = new DataAcc();

    public int id { get; set; }
    public string UserName { get; set; }
    public string Password { get; set; }

    public bool getuser()
    {
        if(sda.DA_Bind().Tables[0].Rows.Count==0)
        {
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@UseName", UserName);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Passwors", Password);
            return false;
        }
        else
        {
            return true;
        }
    }
}
```

Login page code

```
public partial class login : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    protected void btnSave_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        business obj = new business();
        obj.UserName = txtUser.Text;
        obj.Password = txtEmail.Text;

        if(obj.getuser())
        {
            Session["User"] = obj.UserName;
            Response.Redirect("mainpage.aspx");
        }
        else
        {
            Response.Redirect("Please enter correct username and password");
        }
    }
 }
```

Stored procedure:

```
Alter procedure Sp_select
    (@UserName varchar(50),
     @Password varchar(50))
AS 
BEGIN
    Select * 
    from tb_login 
    where UserName = @UserName 
      and Password = @Password
END
```

Comment: Side note: you should **not** use the `sp_` prefix for your stored procedures. Microsoft has [reserved that prefix for its own use (see *Naming Stored Procedures*)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190669%28v=sql.105%29.aspx), and you do run the risk of a name clash sometime in the future. [It's also bad for your stored procedure performance](http://www.sqlperformance.com/2012/10/t-sql-queries/sp_prefix). It's best to just simply avoid `sp_` and use something else as a prefix - or no prefix at all!

Comment: Also, it appears that you're storing the password in **clear text** in your database. This is a **HUGE SECURITY NO-NO** - do **NOT** do this - ***EVER*** ! If you really must store passwords, you need to **hash them and add a salt** - that's the only accepted, somewhat safe approach

Comment: What's the error?

Comment: Thanks for reply...but i am practicing and i dont know naming and all that but thanks i will take care of that

Comment: error is:Additional information: Procedure or function 'Sp_select' expects parameter '@UserName', which was not supplied.

Answer (score 0):

You should provide @UseName and @Passwors, mind the typos :), before executing the procedure. Something like this:

```
public DataSet DA_Bind(string user, string password)
{
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("Sp_select", con);

    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure; 
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@UseName", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = user;
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@Passwors", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = password;

    SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
    DataSet ds = new DataSet();
    da.Fill(ds);
    return ds;
}
```

Comment: You should check out [Can we stop using AddWithValue() already?](http://blogs.msmvps.com/jcoehoorn/blog/2014/05/12/can-we-stop-using-addwithvalue-already/) and stop using `.AddWithValue()` - it can lead to unexpected and surprising results...

Comment: You're right @marc_s, I just moved his code, but it's a good point.